# How to filter the result of array of objects having different keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to get the difference of array of objects having different keys by comparing the value?

```js
const array1 = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  type: 'car'
}]

const array2 = [{
    year: '2020',
    carName: 'BMW',
    model: 'SUV',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2019',
    carName: 'Benz',
    model: 'Sedan',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    carName: 'Audi',
    model: 'Coupe',
    value: 'car'
  }
]

const result = array1.filter(
  ({
    car: id1
  }) =>
  !array2.some(({
    carName: id2
  }) => id2 === id1)
);

console.log('Result ', result)
```

Below is what I'm expecting. The resultant array should filter out the results that are **not** there in `array1`

```
[
  {
    year: '2019',
    carName: 'Benz',
    model: 'Sedan',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    carName: 'Audi',
    model: 'coupe',
    value: 'car'
  }
]
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compare the `name` with `carName`.

```js
const array1 = [{ name: 'BMW', type: 'car' }],
      array2 = [{ year: '2020', carName: 'BMW', model: 'SUV', value: 'car' }, { year: '2019', carName: 'Benz', model: 'Sedan', value: 'car' }, { year: '2018', carName: 'Audi', model: 'Coupe', value: 'car'} ],
      result = array2.filter(o => !array1.some(({name}) => name === o.carName));
console.log('Result ', result)
```

Comment: Perfect.. If someone want to compare objects with multiple keys . e.g name & type,  then he can use  !array1.some(({name, type}) => name === o.carName && type === o.value));

Comment: Yes, that's the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out array2 by comparing its `name` with `carName` property. This will give you items of `array2` that are not in `array1`

```js
const array1 = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  type: 'car'
}]

const array2 = [{
    year: '2020',
    carName: 'BMW',
    model: 'SUV',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2019',
    carName: 'Benz',
    model: 'Sedan',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    carName: 'Audi',
    model: 'Coupe',
    value: 'car'
  }
]
var result = array2.filter(function(obj) {
  return !array1.some(function(obj2) {
    return obj.carName === obj2.name;
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in you code. Use comparison with `name` and `carName` instead of `carName` and `carName`. This code should work:

```
array2.filter(({carName}) => !array1.some(({name}) => name === carName));
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  type: 'car'
}]

const array2 = [{
    year: '2020',
    carName: 'BMW',
    model: 'SUV',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2019',
    carName: 'Benz',
    model: 'Sedan',
    value: 'car'
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    carName: 'Audi',
    model: 'Coupe',
    value: 'car'
  }
]
   const result1 = array2.filter(value => array1.some(arr1Val => arr1Val.name !== 
   value.carName))
console.log('Result ', result1)
```